Auto moving a copied row to the first row set that is empty
I have created an Excel document that has multiple sheets. The first sheet is where all the information is processed, and then I added a formula that transfers the row of information to another sheet if two different word conditions are met.
My only problem is the row that the information is taken from goes to the sheet in the same row space. I want the copied information to move up to the first empty row slot. Please let me know what you need and if you can help me. Here is my current formula that works almost.
I plan to have this formatted to the first 500 rows. Also, The copied information takes from Column B to O. The words I want come from D & L as shown below. Please show me how to add a feature that moves this copied information up to the first available empty cell.
=IF(AND('Applicants for Interview'!L2="Accepted", 'Applicants for Interview'!D2="PA"), 'Applicants for Interview'!B2:O2, "")

I don't know how to use VBA, I tried, and failed a lot. I have tried using ChatGPT, but it never gives me the correct formula.

I think you'll want to use PowerQuery.  Make your dataset a table and use PowerQuery to 'filter' to the new sheet.

Paste this formula into cell B2 of the sheet onto which you wish to copy the information:
=INDEX('Applicants for Interview'!B$2:B$500,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW('Applicants for Interview'!B$2:B$500)-ROW('Applicants for Interview'!B$1))/('Applicants for Interview'!$L$2:$L$500="Accepted")/('Applicants for Interview'!$D$2:$D$500="PA"),ROWS(B$2:B2)))

After the formula is activated drag the fill handle over to cell O2 and then, while cells B2:O2 are still selected, drag the fill handle down to cell O500.
